# How to run external program from Julia and wait until it finishes, then read its output

Tags: julia

I'm trying to execute external program from Julia via `run`, then wait until it finishes and store its **output into a variable**.

The only solution I came up with is this:

```
callback = function(data)
  print(data)
end

open(`minizinc com.mzn com.dzn`) do f
  x = readall(f)
  callback(x)
end
```

The problem is that I **do not want to use callbacks**.

Is there any way, how to wait until the process is finished and then continue in executing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just call `readall` (or `readstring` on Julia master) on the command object:

```
julia> readall(`echo Hello`)
"Hello\n"
```